# How to call Type Methods within an instance method

Tags: ios, class, methods, types, swift

Apple has a nice [explanation of Type (Class) Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html), however, their example looks like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    class func someTypeMethod() {
        // type method implementation goes here
    }
}
SomeClass.typeMethod()
```

I see this exact same example parroted everywhere. My problem is, I need to call my Type Method from within an instance of my class, and that doesn't seem to compute.

I MUST be doing something wrong, but I noticed that Apple does not yet support Class Properties. I'm wondering if I'm wasting my time.

I tried this in a playground:

```
class ClassA
{
    class func staticMethod() -> String { return "STATIC" }

    func dynamicMethod() -> String { return "DYNAMIC" }

    func callBoth() -> ( dynamicRet:String, staticRet:String )
    {
        var dynamicRet:String = self.dynamicMethod()
        var staticRet:String = ""

//        staticRet = self.class.staticMethod() // Nope
//        staticRet = class.staticMethod() // No way, Jose
//        staticRet = ClassA.staticMethod(self) // Uh-uh
//        staticRet = ClassA.staticMethod(ClassA()) // Nah
//        staticRet = self.staticMethod() // You is lame
//        staticRet = .staticMethod() // You're kidding, right?
//        staticRet = this.staticMethod() // What, are you making this crap up?
//        staticRet = staticMethod()  // FAIL

        return ( dynamicRet:dynamicRet, staticRet:staticRet )
    }
}

let instance:ClassA = ClassA()
let test:( dynamicRet:String, staticRet:String ) = instance.callBoth()
```

Does anyone have a clue for me?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In Swift 3 you can use:

```
let me = type(of: self)
me.staticMethod()
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the tip.

Comment: Works, but someone else who thinks this is ugly?

Comment: Indeed, what I'm doing is: `let me = type(of: self)` and then `me.staticMethod()`

Comment: Why did I read somewhere that Swift 3 introduced a new capitalized `Self` keyword to represent the current class? I tried it and it doesn't seem to work at all, nor can I even find reference of it now.

Comment: Is is really still this awkward to call a class function in Swift?

Comment: @devios1 Only if you don't want to write the class name

Comment: I prefer using type(of:self), because I want the option to subclass and extend. And, yes, it is EXTREMELY awkward. I would have liked maybe an all-caps ("SELF") to represent the class (Capitalized "Self" is too subtle. I could look at that all day, and not see the problem).

Comment: A little lesl ugly: `type(of: self).staticMethod()`

Answer (score 103):

```
var staticRet:String = ClassA.staticMethod()
```

This works. It doesn't take any parameters so you don't need to pass in any. You can also get ClassA dynamically like this:

**Swift 2**

```
var staticRet:String = self.dynamicType.staticMethod()
```

**Swift 3**

```
var staticRet:String = type(of:self).staticMethod()
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I have no idea why I didn't try that one. I'll greencheck you as soon as the time limit is up, Speedy Gonzales.

Comment: I just realized why I didn't try that. The autofill insists on inserting a ClassA instance in there when I do that. Not sure why...

Comment: self.dynamicType.staticMethod() did not work for me.

Comment: Its just Woww, where you got this 'dynamicType' ? I didn't find it in document.

Comment: @RoNiT: [Here you go](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID455)

Comment: this `dynamicType` thing is what I've been trying to find for the past few days... thank you!

Comment: In Swift 3 type(of: self) replaces self.dynamicType

Comment: that's just retarded how swift handles this situation, in ObjC you had "[[self class] someMethod]" and in Swift "type(of:self).someMethod()" the winner is clear for me

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add one more twist to this old question.

In today's Swift (I think it switched at 4, but I am not sure), we have replaced `type(of: self)` with `Self` (Note the capital "S").