# Static member 'transition' cannot be used on instance of type 'UIView'

Tags: swift, uiview, static, instance, transition

I try to use view transition for multiple element but get this mistake: 
Static member 'transition' cannot be used on instance of type 'UIView'.
I've read similar discussions but couldn't implement them for my case.
Could you help me?

Here is my code:

```
  func flip03() {

    for item in aGameObjects {


        if positionCounter == 0 {



            item.transition(from: backImageView, to: frontImageView, duration: 1, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)

            frontImageView.image = UIImage(named: "apple")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            frontImageView.tintColor = UIColor.occasionalColor

            positionCounter = 1

        } else {

            item.transition(from: frontImageView, to: backImageView, duration: 1, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)

            positionCounter = 0
        }


    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's because transition is a class method, you can call class method like this:

```
UIView.transition(from: backImageView, to: frontImageView, duration: 1, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
```

for more details on class methods see:

[Calling Type Methods Within An Instance Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472399/calling-type-methods-within-an-instance-method)

and also:

[What is the difference between static func and class func in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156377/what-is-the-difference-between-static-func-and-class-func-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help me to get this transition by all items of the array.