# How to get class of instance and call class function in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

In Objective-C, it was simple to get the class of an instance and call class methods on it.  How do you do this in Swift 4?

e.g.

```
MyObject * obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[[obj class] someClassMethod];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Type Methods Within An Instance Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472399/calling-type-methods-within-an-instance-method)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `type(of)` method to get the class of an object, and use this to call a class method on it.

```
class MyObject {
  static func someClassMethod() {

  }
}
let obj = MyObject()
type(of: obj).someClassMethod()
```